# Can I boot into Linux without grub?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have 2 operating systems on my computer: Windows and Linux. I had to reinstall Windows for a long complicated issue after I had Linux installed on my computer which deleted or at least hid the grub boot loader. Is there any way I can boot into Linux without it? I know there are already questions on this, but every answer assumes I can access Linux. I can't, which is the entire reason I'm asking this. And downloading another boot loader or something won't work because the entire reason I want to get into Linux is to help fix an issue with my Windows that is preventing it from connecting to the internet.

Comment: Ask about the windows question instead on [su]. Don't fall in [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is fix the issue with Windows, I suggest that you get a live cd of a Linux distro and boot into it. If needed, you can install it; the next time you boot up your computer, grub will show up. Just make sure that you enable the "install grub" option when installing.

If you log into a live session, you can remove Linux, if needed.

You *need* a bootloader ot boot into an OS.